# How to find IP address of .local domain?

Tags: networking, dns

How to map a `.local` domain to IP address?

My LAN has a raspberry pi running, which I normally access like `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`. However, for opening services in a web browser, I need the IP address (e.g. http://192.168.1.100:9091/transmission), which I can manually check in my router's configuration. Is there any command that would translate `raspberrypi.local` to the local IP address of the device?

Comment: If you are able to use the name at the command line, then I am surprised by it not working in your browser, though, I am not familiar with Transmission’s web interface. Be sure that you are specifying `http://raspberrypi.local:9091/transmission` in full (the http portion being important). If that doesn’t work, then please specify the OS you are using. Also note that many routers allow you to set static IP addresses for devices on your network. This would allow you to have the Pi always set to whatever IP you wanted it to have.

Comment: Yes, apparently with the correct configuration, transmission works with the hostname too (need to set `rpc-host-whitelist` field)

Answer (score 0):

`gethostip -d rasperrypi.local` will show the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ping -a rasperrypi.local`